# Eigenvector Sensitivity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The  Maximum Likelihood Estimator in a model I am studying depends on the eigenvectors of a symmetric positive definite (covariance) matrix ${\bf{X}}$ (3000 * 3000). I believe that the answer ought to be very sensitive to the eigenvectors of ${\bf{X}}$ (which depends on the people used on the sample) and am trying to prove it. My line of approach is as follows: When I plug in a slightly new covariance matrix (${\bf{X}} + \Delta{\bf{X}}$) the MLEs change a lot. My task is now to classify $\Delta{\bf{X}}$ in some meaningful way to aid in my analysis

Certain theories guarantee that all the eigenvalues of ${\bf{X}}$ will be in the interval [0,4]. Thus, the smallest separation between any 2 eigenvalues (assuming ${\bf{X}}$ is non-degenerate in the best case) will be very small.

When this happens, the eigenvectors become very sensitive to small perturbations, for instance

[image]

where sep(D1,D2) is the minimum absolute difference between an eigenvalue in D1 and an eigenvalue in D2. I am struggling with a way to define a ${\bf{P}}$ matrix for the purpose of analysis. (1) For simplicity, even when r=1, I feel I cannot claim $||{\bf{P}}||$ is large naively because I have no idea what $E_{21}$ will be and (2) the theorem claims that $||{\bf{P}}||$ is bounded above by some number (and there exists some ${\bf{P}}$ for which this is tight).

Is there (a) any tighter handle for ${\bf{P}}$ I could use or (b) is there any exact result for perturbations of eigenvectors of symmetric matrices (Positive definite in my case) which I could use?

Thank you very much for any help your could provide